# GWT Maven build with Place Annotations

Tags: gwt, maven

I'm attempting to convert my GWT app to build with maven.  The first issue I've his is that the compiler does not seem to like the "@WithTokenizers" I have in my PlaceHistoryMapper - at least that's what I think is failing and if I comment those out the application will compile.  Do I need to put some extra configuration in my pom to get this to work?  It compiles fine in eclipse or if I attempt the maven build after eclipse has already compiled the GWT source.

Here's the exception I get:

```
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin
:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project product_ui_administration: Compilation failure
\workspaces\java\product_ui_administration\src\main\java\com\company\product\ui\administration\AdminPlaceHistoryMapper.java:[13,0] illega
l start of expression

        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
\workspaces\java\product_ui_administration\src\main\java\com\company\product\ui\administration\AdminPlaceHistoryMapper.java:[13,0] illega
l start of expression

        at org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:656)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        ... 19 more
[ERROR]
```

Here is my AdminPlaceHistoryMapper interface

```
// this annotation not working in mvn for some reason
@WithTokenizers({
    UserDetailsPlace.Tokenizer.class,
    UserPermissionsPlace.Tokenizer.class,
    CompanyDetailsPlace.Tokenizer.class,
})

public interface AdminPlaceHistoryMapper extends PlaceHistoryMapper {   
}
```

Comment: Please add your `AdminPlaceHistoryMapper.java` file.

Comment: added AdminPlaceHistoryMapper.java

Comment: Are you compiling with a 1.5 version of the JDK ? (see http://twit88.com/blog/2008/03/09/maven-compile-your-application-to-be-14-15-or-16-compatible/)

Comment: does the '@' character comes from a copy&paste, or is it a "real" character (ie encoding problem) ?

Comment: its a real character.  it's used to specify a Java annotation and I have the library defining that annotation in my maven dependencies.

Comment: What I was trying to say, is that you actually type the '@' and it did not come from a copy&paste (ie a unicode character rendered correctly by your text editor), or maybe you have an hidden character before the '@'. Try to remove the line, and retype it.

Comment: To the OP: please upvote the answer you selected as correct! :)

Comment: @helios - I posted my own answer (& I can't upvote that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a simple syntax problem that the Eclipse compiler ignored, but the maven GWT compiler flagged.

[From the "gwt-maven-plugin Users" Google Group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/codehaus-mojo-gwt-maven-plugin-users/01hOfIRod1I/qhsrYIDZLMsJ)

> This seems pretty clear to me, it even gives you the line number...
>
> Anyhow, you can not legally have a comma character at the end of your
>   Tokenizer list. That is a syntax error. Your Eclipse compiler
>   tolerated it, but most other compilers will not.
>
> -Jesse

Comment: As a sidenote: if you have an array declaration it's legal to have an ending-comma. I think it's in homogeneusness sake...